# why torchvision.models.alexnet() not work when i test the input and output?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, mismatch, conv-neural-network, torchvision

The Code is here:

```
import torch
from torchvision.models import alexnet

if __name__ == "__main__":
    net = alexnet()
    x = torch.rand((1, 3, 224, 224))

    for name, layer in net.named_children():
        x = layer(x)
        print(name, ' output shape:\t', x.shape)
```

The output is here:

```
features  output shape:  torch.Size([1, 256, 6, 6])
avgpool  output shape:   torch.Size([1, 256, 6, 6])

File "AlexNet.py", line 9, in <module>
    x = layer(x)
RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [1536 x 6], m2: [9216 x 4096]
```

I want to test the input and output of the AlexNet, but i failed with the 'size mismatch' error. i use the image size(3,224,224) provided by the paper of AlexNet, and i wanna get the right output. After this error, i try to fix the

```
self.avgpool = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d((6, 6))
```

to

```
self.avgpool = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d((1, 9216))
```

and i get the right output.

I really want to know what did i do wrong with the torchvision. And i also want to know the what people would do when they need to test the input and output of the cnn.

thx for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. I missed the flatten `x = torch.flatten(x, 1)`[code](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/d45a77d414082bf5ccbf65355354f583d43a40c0/torchvision/models/alexnet.py#L47) by this way

```
for name, layer in net.named_children():
    x = layer(x)
    print(name, ' output shape:\t', x.shape)
```

thx for your help!